# Bash: "invalid number" error when passing array elements value to variable

Tags: arrays, bash, posix

I run GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu). A very simple script called from cmd line with at least 3 arbitrary arguments:

```
#!/bin/bash

n_arg=$#
arr=("$@") 
AA=${arr[0]}   # CHANGED FROM AA=S{arr[0]}
BB=${arr[1]}   # CHANGED FROM BB=S{arr[1]}

for (( i = 2; i < "$n_arg"; i++ )); do
    printf "%d   %s   %s   %s\n" $i $AA $BB  ${arr[i]}  # <- line 9
    # printf "%d   %s   %s   %s\n" $i "$AA" "$BB"  ${arr[i]}  # ALSO TRIED
done
exit 0
```

yields an error as shown below:

```
$ script.sh 10 2 13 443
./script.sh: line 9: printf: S{arr[0]}: invalid number
./script.sh: line 9: printf: S{arr[1]}: invalid number
2    0   0   13
./script.sh: line 9: printf: S{arr[0]}: invalid number
./script.sh: line 9: printf: S{arr[1]}: invalid number
3    0   0   443
```

I can see that the value of the first and second array elements passed to AA and BB respectively seems to pose a prbm I don't quite scope. I did try:
 AA="S{arr[0]}"
When I type in the code in interactive mode, everything goes smoothly.

Comment: `S`?  Do you mean `$`?  As, in `AA=${arr[0]}`

Comment: Sounds like you need glasses or a better font. =)

Comment: [ProggyFont](http://www.proggyfonts.net/) rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`S` looks like `$`, especially when you're tired.  I use a [font](http://www.proggyfonts.net/) designed to clearly distinguish homoglyphs like that -- highly recommended.

Arrays are not part of the [POSIX shell standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html).  You can roll your own polyfill, or use a [pre-fab one](https://github.com/makefu/array).

Comment: Just a vaguely lame and off topic but real short comment: .... I took yr advice and downloaded/installed the proggy TTF. It looks really bad in terminal on my 1680x1050 display, because due to high screen res I have to increase font size from default 12 to 16 to be able to read clearly ... So unless there is a solution to legibly scale TTF available in terminal , it's a no go for me. Pity but advice much appreciated.

Comment: @Cbhihe  Similar situation here, 1920x1080 FHD, the font looks jagged at high point size.  I've come to consider that a benefit, though. Not only do I get a bit of daily nostalgia from the 1993 BBS feel (which even strangers comment on), but I can clearly read it from far away with my wireless keyboard.  But I guess it's like snails in butter -- an acquired taste.  That said, there are a few really good anti-aliased monospace programmer's fonts.  [Here's a great article listing 10 of them.](http://hivelogic.com/articles/top-10-programming-fonts)